# Changing XML SVG fill within a URL

Tags: html, css, svg, fill

Trying to understand the format of the fill, so I can change the color for the appropriate design.

Standard bootstrap 5 accordion arrow.

```css
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23212529'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
```

Fill='%23212529'
what format is this so I can change it?

Comment: %23 is URL encoding of #. The rest is just the RGB of the fill per https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#rgb-color

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use like this
fill='%230f70d0'

So,

- %23 => #
- 0f70d0 => Color hex code excerpt #

after %23 you can use color hex code
Example: #0f70d0 => %230f70d0